# rsUnknownUserName in Reporting Services 2012

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

The username ' ' is not recognized. rsUnknownUsername is stopping me to create new user-role in Reporting ServiceSQL2012(both in system level and item level.
Anyone have any idea how to overcome this issue?
Please shed light on this.

Answer (score 0):

in report manager > folder settings > security set folder permission to user. I'm afraid I do not have any report server available to explain in details but I think your issue causes by that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is not working. Still having rsUnknownUserName issue.